# What's the difference between dismax and should?

Tags: elasticsearch

I can't see a difference between the results of the following queries #1 and #2.
The results are the same, so why do we have 2 separate queries?
What's the difference between dismax and should?

Query 1:

```
GET products/_search
{
  "query": {
    "dis_max": {
      "queries": [
        {
          "range": {
            "price": {
              "gte": 800,
              "lte": 1000
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase_prefix": {
            "overview": "4k ultra hd"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Query 2:

```
GET products/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "range": {
            "price": {
              "gte": 800,
              "lte": 1000
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase_prefix": {
            "overview": "4k ultra hd"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: per the elastic docs the dis_max.queries translates to it must match one or more queries
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-dis-max-query.html
in case of should you can achieve the same using the minimum_should_match
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-minimum-should-match.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two queries calculate the score for each hit differently. Scores of individual subqueries in `should` are added together, while in `dismax` only the highest score is kept.

The `range` query will give you the score of 1 if price is in the range and score of 0 if price is not in the range. The `match_phrase_prefix` query will return different score depending on how they match or 0 if it doesn't match. You can see it on the following example:

```
DELETE test

PUT test/_bulk
{"index": {}}
{"overview": "4k ultra hd tv", "price": 820}
{"index": {}}
{"overview": "hd tv", "price": 810}
{"index": {}}
{"overview": "4k ultra hd ultra cheap tv", "price": 120}

POST test/_search?explain=false
{
  "query": {
    "dis_max": {
      "queries": [
        {
          "range": {
            "price": {
              "gte": 800,
              "lte": 1000
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase_prefix": {
            "overview": "4k ultra hd"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

POST test/_search?explain=false
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "range": {
            "price": {
              "gte": 800,
              "lte": 1000
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase_prefix": {
            "overview": "4k ultra hd"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If you run this you will see that in case of `should` the first record, which matches both range (with score 1) and query (with score 1.0735388) will return you total score of `1 + 1.0735388 = 2.0735388`. If you `dismax` on the same data the first record will have score of `max(1, 1.0735388) = 1.0735388`. The rest of the records only match a single query, in which case the total score will be the same in both cases.